# RaspberryPI use with 3G/4G dongle

Tags: pi-3b+, remote, internet

I've been looking into a project which would require me to enable my PI to have a remote internet connection. I'm wondering if the PI is able to use a 3G/4G dongle for this?

If it can, does anyone have any suggestions on which model/make of dongle is best to use and any instructions on setting up the dongle withe my PI?

Comment: Shopping requests are explicitly [off-topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: You can search 4G / LTE / module / dongle for more details in this forum.